# not able to add contact in android

Tags: react-native, react-native-contacts

I am trying to add a new contact to the Address book using react-native-contacts plugin, however I am getting the following error

java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: writing com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2 uri content://com.android.contacts/raw_contacts from pid=30018, uid=10148 requires android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS, or grantUriPermission()

added these permissions on AndroidMainfest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
```

import Contacts from 'react-native-contacts'

let newPerson = {
      recordID: '507',
      rawContactId: '504',
      givenName: values.givenName,
      familyName: values.familyName,
      phoneNumbers: [
        {
          label: values.type,
          number: values.phoneNumber,
        },
      ],
      emailAddresses: [
        {
          label: 'my email label',
          email: 'test@test.com',
        },
      ],
    }
    Contacts.addContact(newPerson, (err, contact) => {
      if (err) throw err
      console.log(contact)
      // save successful
    })

It should add contact to the address book

Comment: what version of react native and android are your running? please use the latest versions of android, react-native and react-native-contacts

Answer (score 0):

You need to ask your phone for writing permission on your app load (or any other time u wanna add new contacts).

```
PermissionsAndroid.request(
  PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_CONTACTS,
  {
    'title': 'Contacts',
    'message': 'This app would like to view your contacts.',
    'buttonPositive': 'Please accept bare mortal'
  }
)
```

ask permission from your phone like mentioned above.